# Boundedness of $\sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \frac{k}{m^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the series $\sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \frac{k}{m^2}$ bounded independently of k?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\frac 1{m^2}\leqslant \sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\frac 1{m(m-1)}$, which behave approximatively as $\frac 1k$.

Answer (score 5):

I think there was to prove a uniform bound, $k$-indipendent.
Assuming $k\geq 2$ we have:
$$\sum_{m=k}^{+\infty}\frac{k}{m^2}<k\int_{k-1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{k}{k-1}\leq 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\sum_{m=k}^{n}\frac{k}{m^2}=k\sum_{m=k}^{n}\frac{1}{m^2}\le k\sum_{m=k}^{n}\frac{1}{m(m-1)}=k\sum_{m=k}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{(m-1)}-\frac{1}{(m)}\right)=k\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)}-\frac{1}{(n)}\right)\le \frac{k}{k-1}\le 2$

Comment: It does not show the sum is bounded independently of k, or dependently of k.

Comment: Now I think its ok @eccstartup